# Odd behavior in use of simple directive of validations messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
App.directive("validateMsgFor", function(){
    return{
        templateUrl : "view/templates/validateMsgFor.html",
        restrict:  "E",
        scope: {
            field : "="
        }
    }
});
```

And the template that it uses is this:

```
<div ng-if="field.$dirty" ng-messages="field.$error">
    <div ng-messages-include="view/messages.html"></div>
</div>
```

which in turn uses the following html:

```
<div class="messages">
    <div ng-message="required">Campo Obrigatório</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Necessário mais caracteres</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Necessário menos caracteres</div>
    <div ng-message="email">E-mail inválido</div>
    <div ng-message="compareTo">Deve corresponder com valor digitado anteriormente</div>
</div>
```

All this to be used as follows:

```
<label>Departamento</label> 
<select id="departamentos" ng-model="model.curso.departamento" name="departamento" ng-options="d.nome for d in departamentos track by d.id" ng-required="true">
    <option value="">Selecione um Departamento</option>
</select>
<validate-msg-for field="mainForm.departamento"></validate-msg-for>
```

It works the way I expect, that is to show the message when there is a validation error and when the field is with the status "dirty".
But when I click on another link, that is, when I go to another page, the tab freezes, begin to use a lot the processor,  indicating some kind of infinite loop or something, and then the page breaks.  I realized this only happens when the message is appearing on the page, and when I comment the  the problem does not happen.

My question is to know what I'm doing wrong, is not the way I should I use?
And if anyone has any suggestions?

The angular, angular-route and angular-messages versions that I am using are 1.4.3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did the following change:

```
<div ng-if="field.$dirty" ng-messages="field.$error" class="messages">
    <div ng-message="required">Campo Obrigatório</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">Necessário mais caracteres</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Necessário menos caracteres</div>
    <div ng-message="email">E-mail inválido</div>
    <div ng-message="compareTo">Deve corresponder com valor digitado anteriormente</div>
    <!-- <div ng-messages-include="view/messages.html"></div> -->
</div>
```

And now it works without crashing.

However, still don't know why that error happened.